# correct way to catch a created exception

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following `class exception`:

```
namespace A{
 namespace B{
   namespace C{
     class internal_error : public std::runtime_error{
        public:
             explicit internal_error(const std::string &arg) : std::runtime_error(arg) {};
     };
    }
   }
  }
```

And in my code I have:

```
try{
  if(mkdipath(dirname, DIR_CREATION_MODE, &err)){
       string msg;
       msg = "failed to create path " + *dirname;
       logmsg(MSERROR, msg.c_str(), who);
       throw A::B::C::internal_error(msg);
  }
}
catch(){
    // how am I going to catch a A::B::C::internal_error?
}
```

My question is : how am I going to catch a A::B::C::internal_error?
Should I use:

```
catch(A::B::C::internal_error &error){
      string msg("You should never had happened\n");
      logmsg(MSERROR, msg.c_str(), who);
}
```

Please ignore the tags `MSERROR`, `who`, `mkdirpath` ... they are not important to the question.

Comment: Does this code not work?

Comment: Remove the _ before internal_error, so it become A::B::C::internal_error

Comment: I removed ... my question is: am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
catch(A::B::C::internal_error &error){
    //...
}
```

is fine, note sure where the leading underscore came from, probably a typo.

Comment: @philippe how should i know? maybe just logging it like you did is enough, maybe you would want to close the apllication, or try again with different path.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
// ...
} catch (const A::internal_error& ex) {
// ...
} catch (const B::internal_error& ex) {
// ...
} catch (const C::internal_error& ex) {
// ...
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Even you can use  a string argument as exception. like: std::string& ex) {